# How to Add signed 8-bit from unsigned 16-bit?

Tags: c, casting, unsigned, signed

I'm having trouble understanding how to do the following:

I have an array of `uint8_t` elements. From this array, I want to acquire an element and add it to a `uint16_t` item. However I want to interpret this `uint8_t` value as a signed value for the purposes of this operation.

```
uint16_t A;
uint8_t  B;
uint16_t result;

result = A + (int8_t)B;
```

However I learned that this casting might not work. I can't think of any other way to get this to work. It's important that the elements of my array remain as `uint8_t` otherwise. Only for this operation, do I want the `uint8_t` element interpreted as a signed value (`int8_t`).

Comment: Is the casting actually failing, or you are worried about something you heard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been misinformed: There is nothing wrong with your code, and nothing that supports the claim that *this casting might not work*.

Technically, there is a very slim possibility that the type `int8_t` be unavailable on your system, but in this very unlikely case, `uint8_t` would not be defined either. Such systems include some DSPs and some obsolete mainframes.  If you are programming to a more mainstream system, don't worry about it.

Comment: It turns out I had a severe misunderstanding. In C the final result will be promoted to an unsigned value for mixed type operations. I misunderstood this to mean that casting will have no effect in such operations.

Comment: @thejonny: that's not exactly true: it depends on the size of `int` on your system.  It `int` is 16 bits, the same as `int16_t`, then `(int8_t)B` is converted to `unsigned int`, which involves an initial sign extension and the operation `A + (int8_t)B` is performed on `unsigned int`. If `int` is larger than 16 bits, both operands are promoted to `int` and the result of the operation is converted down to `uint16_t` when stored to `result`.  Both methods give the same result on 2s complement architectures.

Comment: @chqrlie I was incorrectly seeing a potential different signed integer overflow and have removed my comment.